# ASP.net Calendar Control conditional

Tags: asp.net

I want to have a calendar control to only allow users to select dates which are weekdays (Mon-Fri) in the future and if it's after eg. 9.00 am of the current day then this date will also not be available, this to be then returned into a text box.

How can a do this easily. I'm still very new to ASP.net.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.IsWeekend == true)
        {
            e.Cell.Enabled = false;
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cell.Enabled = true;

            if (e.Day.Date == DateTime.Today)
            {
                // DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 9)
                {
                    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                    e.Cell.Enabled = false;
                    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.Enabled = false;
                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }

        }

    }
```

**Update:**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" 
            ></asp:Calendar>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>




protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, how do I call the Calendar_DayRender event?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, how do I call the Calendar_DayRender event? Do I put the following code in the aspx page    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged></asp:Calendar>
How do I now add a text box to insert the date selected by the user? Thank you.

Comment: Hi I tried didn't work, I had error that System.EventArgs does not contain a definition for Day and Cell. And the name Color does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I have update my answer, please look at that and you need to add namespace to use color (using System.Drawing;) you can see event of controls on right click on that and go to property>event tab..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update, but I'm still getting an error for e.Day 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Day' and no extension method 'Day' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). This same error also shows for e.Cell

Comment: Please check your dayrender event defination in .cs file as per bleow
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) , should be DayRenderEventArgs instead of  EventArgs

Comment: Hi,thank you so much for helping me. Now I have the calendar but the criteria are not working, the weekends are colour grey but I can still click and dates prior to 9.00am today is also clickable and shows up in the textbox. Can you also please show how to only show the date and not datetime in the textbox? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Add  e.Day.IsSelectable = false; wherever  e.Cell.Enabled = false; exist in above code

Comment: Hi I tried: if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 9)
                    {
                        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    } this does not work it still allows all date to be selectable. The weekend one works.

Comment: I have updated dayrender event so please replace it , just added another elseif loop..

Answer (score 1):

Handle the DayRender event:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsWeekend == true)
    {
        e.Cell.Enabled = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }

    // add your other criteria as needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for asp.net on VB you can use this :

```
 Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)
            If (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday) Then
                e.Day.IsSelectable = False
                e.Cell.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
            If e.Day.Date < System.DateTime.Today Then
                e.Day.IsSelectable = False
            End If

 End Sub
```

This will disable the dates before today and disable selection of weekend.